# How to figure the next number in this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, puzzle

This question has been asked as a puzzle in a forum of an online game, but I coudn't solve it neither any of the members of the forum, so I asked for help here.

giving this sequence of numbers

```
1 > 170
2 > 344
3 > 520
4 > 698
5 > 875
6 > 1052
8 > x
16 > 2811
20 > y
```

What would be x and y based on that sequence ?

the moderator has given us a hint after 2 days , but we still can't figure it out, the Hint is:

based on

```
a > b
c > d
```

calculating the number $a*d - c*b$ for each row should give us a clue.

I noticed that $d = (c*b + z) / a$

and $z = a*d - c*b$

The problem is that d and z both are unknowns and the 2 formulas are the same so I can't figure out 2 unknowns in the same formula.

**How to figure out x and y ?**

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to format.

Comment: @Saad Ok just give me sometime to know how  does it work and I will edit the question and use it

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:calculus] (and [tag:linear-algebra])?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner What tags should I use ? I don't know

Comment: Consider tagging [tag:puzzle] (perhaps [tag:sequences-and-series] or [tag:recreational-mathematics] too)

Comment: Are you sure you transcribed the numbers correctly? When I calculate $ad-bc$ for each row, I get $4, 8, 14, 10, 10, ...$ for the sequence of $z$ that you show. If this were supposed to be a straightforward sequence, I would have expected either $z$ to be constant, or for it to be an "obvious" sequence. Can you check your input again, then?

Comment: @PrimeMover Yes I double checked the input, and yes this is the same sequence I got 4,8,10,10 , when I told the moderator of that sequence he said," well, what do you notice from that sequence ?" but I can't see any clue from that sequence 4,8,10,10 !

Comment: @PrimeMover sorry I mean 4,8,14,10,10 not 4,8,10,10

Comment: Not even anything on OEIS. Nope, drawn a blank. Sorry.

Comment: It seems that that they just want their hint to make a symmetric pattern, just like Yves said, thank you very much for your time @PrimeMover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the hint,

$$x=1405,y=3514$$ makes a symmetric pattern.

Comment: Please how does the hint lead to this answer ? I'm trying to figure this for more than 24 hours :(

Comment: @Accountantم: I said it.

Comment: I mean how did you calculate that x = 1405 ?  what formula did you use ? how do I calculate the number at the position 7 for example ?

Comment: @Accountantم: no idea, and I am not sure this is possible. Read my answer and check it.

Comment: Or you mean that using these numbers will give a symmetric pattern of  z numbers like for example `4,8,14,10,10,14,8,4` ?

Comment: @Accountantم: that's what I wrote.

Comment: ohhhh yes I get it,  so the idea was to just make a symmetric pattern of z numbers ? thank you very much for your time, I thought there is some formula or something else, thaaaaaaaaaaank you